# Javascript - Convert serialized date string to short date string

Tags: javascript, date

How can I convert a serialized date value (1424246400000) to a short date string ("2/23/2015") in mmddyyyy format using javascript?

I've tried using Date() and all I can seem to come up with is a long string...

```
Date(1424246400000); //"Mon Feb 23 2015 16:56:37 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a simple date string in your current locale format using [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) without any parameters or you can pass *"en-US"* if you want that locale specifically, eg

```js
var d = new Date(1424246400000);
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit'
});
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I did not parse my serialized string to integer, which is required.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue preventing me from using new Date(serializedString)... serializedString must be an integer, not a string.